# caching database queries at midnight?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis

I'm using Redis in combination with laravel to cache some heavy queries in my application like this:

```
return Cache::remember('projects.wip', $this->cacheDuration(), function () {
   ...             
});

private function cacheDuration()
{
   return Carbon::now()->endOfDay()->diffInSeconds(Carbon::now());
}
```

At this moment, the cache expires as midnight, but the first person that passes this method in the morning will be the unlucky one that has to execute the query, so i would like to cache all these queries at midnight again. Is there an easy solution to this? Or will i have to manually mimic http calls to the server at night?

Comment: cronjob calling the page out of the question?

Comment: Is definitely an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good approach to achieve what you're looking for is to use a scheduler that executes at midnight to warm the cache.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling

First, use php artisan to create the command:

```
php artisan make:command WarmCache
```

You should edit it so it looks something like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class WarmCache extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'warmcache';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Warms Cache';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        // >>>> INSERT YOUR CACHE CODE HERE <<<<
    }
}
```

You should add the code that warms your cache in the handle() function, depending on what you're trying to cache you may not need to make a http request. However, you can always use something like curl or guzzle to query the page as a http request if you need to.

Then add this to app/Console/Kernel -> $commands:

```
protected $commands = [
    // ...
    \App\Console\Commands\WarmCache::class,
    // ...
];
```

Also, add this to app/Console\Kernel schedule() function so that it executes at mignight:

```
$schedule->command('warmcache')->daily();
```

Finally, make sure you have set up the crontask that will execute the laravel scheduler:

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Tyvm